# Combine lattice xyplot and histogram

Tags: r, lattice

Could someone help me please to upgrade my plot?
a) In the plot, there should be print only one y-scale per row.
b) To print a more comfortable legend, that means 
1) change the order of symbols and description,
2) print line in the same x-position like superpose.symbols,
3) and print symbols for the histogram.

```
d1 <- data.frame(x=c(NA, 13:20, NA), y = 25, z = c(rep('march', 5),
rep("april", 5)), color = c(c(rep(c("red", "green"), 2), "red"),
c(rep(c("blue", "yellow"), 2), "blue")), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
d2 <- data.frame(x=c(NA, 20:27, NA), y = 23, z = c(rep('may', 5),
rep("june", 5)), color = c(c(rep(c("blue", "red"), 2), "red"),
c(rep(c("blue", "yellow"), 2), "blue")), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
d1<-rbind(d1,d2)
sup.sym <- trellis.par.get("superpose.symbol")
sup.sym$alpha<-c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
sup.sym$col<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

sup.lin <- trellis.par.get("superpose.line")
sup.lin$col<-c(1,2,7,5,5,6,7)
sup.lin$alpha<-c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
settings<-list(superpose.symbol = sup.sym,superpose.line = sup.lin)


xyplot(y ~ x | factor(z), data = d1
       ,ylim = list( c(22, 26),c(22, 26), c(0, 1),c(0, 1) )
       ,layout=c(2,2)
       ,scales = list(y = list( relation = "free"  ))
       ,par.settings = settings
       ,auto.key = list(text = c("A","B","C", "D")
                ,space = "right"
                ,lines = TRUE
               )
       ,panel = function(x, y, subscripts) {
                if(panel.number()>2){
                  panel.histogram(x,breaks=3)
                }else{
                  panel.xyplot(x = x, y = y, 
                               subscripts=subscripts,
                               col = d1[subscripts, "color"])

               }
})
```

Comment: Hi Klaus.  I think that this question hasn't yet been answered for three reasons.  One is that the example seems unnecessarily complex.  It would be better to provide a "minimal working example": code which is as simple as possible, while still illustrating the problem that you want to solve.  The second reason is that you have multiple questions. It would be better to post separate questions. The last difficulty is that the questions aren't yet clear.  For example, what do you mean by "y-scale per row"? Which rows?  (I think the answer might involve the `scales` parameter of `xyplot`.)